# How to architect internal single user credentials that have control over other entities that pretend to be users (facebook pages/company profiles)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-applications, architecture

I'm not sure if that's the best way to ask this question.

I've built a facebook clone.

Now it's coming to the point where I want people to be able to create pages/company profiles.

So I want MANY users to be able to

A) manage these pages (Easy, just authorize the user against the page)

B) Act as those pages, as if they were a normal user account (Make posts on pages, and act throughout the app, as if they were a normal user

Now to do this I could

i) Actually create a new USER which is of a different type. When a normal user wants to act as a PAGE/Company I actually authenticate/authorize them to be able to, and actually switch their signed in account to the second user. When logged in as this user, they can switch back to the other user type using the same method. I actually quite like this idea, as it means very little code change, and everything should work just fine.

Problems - Cookies? Multiple users being signed into the same account at the same time? I'm guessing this is my problem and how I structure my general app/cookie approach

ii) I could just create new types in the db, ie Pages / Companies, and on each place where I have a UserId (Posts, Messages, Photos, Images, etc...) add a PageId and CompanyId. Then when working as a page or a company, I can log which page/company was interacting.

This will result in a fair amount of code change, and also feels hacky, compared to the theorectically clean idea in option a).

However I may have missed some absolutely massive security flaw or other reason why option A) is a bad idea.

Any ideas anyone?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are over-complicating your situation.  You seem to want to do the following:

- Create a `User` model that is your one and only model capable of logging in
- Add the 'other account types' as added levels of authentication within that `User` model

This is akin to adding different `roles` to your `User` models.

- UserA can have a role that allows them to do more things than UserB
- These roles can come and go as necessary

You appear to be on the right track with your method `i`.  [KISS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) comes to mind.

### **Update - based on your comments:**

I would go back to the drawing board on how you want to do this - the apparent structure is too unclean, we need to be more inventive here.

We would be able to help more if we knew a *lot* more information about your exact structure, but that's tedious.  That being said, there is something inherently complicated about your solution that is resulting in these issues.

I'll do my best - this is what comes to mind when I think of your user needs:

- It feels similar to a classroom setting.  You have a bunch of users (Students, Teacher, Administration) who can access the same area (classroom), and there's several of these areas that are similar (different classrooms).
- If it is anything like the classroom setting, you would have users with roles like these:

  - Administrators can access anything anywhere they want.
  - Instructors can access any classroom they explicitly teach.

    - Being an Instructor means they can do more things in the classroom than the students.
  - Students have much more limited permissions and can basically only attend class, turn in homework, and see their grades.  The only thing they are in control of is weather they show up or not.

*At first, the above situation may sound convoluted - how does one set up a permission scheme for this sort of structure?*

## Easy:

- You have three roles: `Admin` `Teacher` `Student`
- (I'm going to over-simplify) You throw `[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]` over every single controller action that requires a user to log in - since they can do anything they want.
- You allow `Teacher`s to have almost all control over any action related to a class they teach: `if User.IsInRole("Teacher") && User.Name == classroom.Teacher`
- You allow `Student`s to have greater restrictions over what they can do and limit further by if they user is actually in the classroom or not: `if User.IsInRole("Student") && User.Name.IsInList().List<Enrollments>EnrollmentListForCurrentClassroom` (very pseudo-codey)

You only have three roles, but you can restrict access to separate parts of the database by more than just the role - you can restrict access by weather the user has also been added to a list of enrolled students in a class, a list of teachers that teach a class (typically only 1 teacher per class. . . ), etc.

Hopefully taking an approach similar to the one above would help simplify your situation.

Comment: Yeah, it is like roles, the issue is does this architectural direction allow all the functionally needed (sharing many users with a single shared account) with other problems down the line?

Comment: Can you clarify your question a bit further with an example?

Comment: Is the idea of automatically signing a user in and out of an app, to a whole new set of credentials (without needing to know the shared accounts password), so that multiple people can share a single set of credentials. The password for the shared credentials will be randomised with a long random password, so nobody can actually log into these accounts directly. Maybe there could be an even more strict way to not allow front end logon. Depends if that interferes with the server side logout/login that could happen.

Comment: OK, now I've implemented a bit of it, and a huge problem rears it's head. Once you've switched into the shared user Acount, how do you switch back to your original account, without bring up all the other many->one users that could have access to the account. Am thinking around it now, but this is starting to feel more hacky than I would like.

Comment: Thanks for the massive response! I've actually put this feature on hold for the moment, as its not top priority. But I still think my idea may work. I understand how you structure roles, but what if you had a situation where you had such a thing as a "Group teacher" which represented say 3 teachers. You wanted any 3 users with normal teacher accounts (so they could still function as indervidual teachers) to be able to become the group teacher account and do specific things with that account. A problem using my methods is once a user switches into the shared account, you don't know who is reall

Comment: y working with the account. To solve this I would log actions taken by the shared account more heavily, so you could trace who was in control of the account at that time, and took actions. Do you use facebook? Do you understand the shared credential model of a facebook "page" for a company lets say? You want 3 employees all to be able to function as that entity, without sharing credentials or having to create new accounts. IE, single sign-on, but within a single website. Ether my idea is kinda clever, or very very stupid. If it works, it means no refactoring, and people can share using

Comment: Entities. Or it is really stupid, and breaks some law of the web.